# Password encryption sha1 php to node js crypto

Tags: php, node.js, sha1, cryptojs

I have this two function in php.

```
public function hashSSHA($password) {
    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted_password = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true).$salt);
    $hash = array("salt"=>$salt, "encrypted"=>$encrypted_password);
    return $hash;
}

//Password Decryption 
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {
    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true).$salt);
    return $hash;
}
```

I am trying to write this two functions in node js.

Here is something I tried.

```
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1', 'my different salt from DB');
hash.update(password);
console.log(hash.digest('base64'));
```

But they both produced different results.

Comment: You do different things. First of all, be sure to use same `salt` and `password`. Then in your php code, you use the `salt` twice while calculating your result. This of course leads to different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Node.js functions should be equivalent to your PHP code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function hashSSHA(password){
    let salt = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(crypto.randomBytes(8)).digest('base64');
    salt = salt.substring(0,10);
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    hash.update(password + salt);
    return {
        salt: salt,
        encrypted: Buffer.concat([hash.digest(), Buffer.from(salt)]).toString('base64')
    };
};

function checkhashSSHA(salt, password) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    hash.update(password + salt);
    return Buffer.concat([hash.digest(), Buffer.from(salt)]).toString('base64');
}

const password = "some password";
const hashResult = hashSSHA(password);
console.log("Hash result: ", hashResult);
console.log("Check hash result: ", checkhashSSHA(hashResult.salt, password));
```

Comment: This is very close.

Comment: Check hash result:  VT3R9IR7dZDX+MHMPZWKfg/aGN8=993f075527 VT3R9IR7dZDX+MHMPZWKfg/aGN85OTNmMDc1NTI3

First is from your node and second from PHP

Comment: the main difference is salt I guess, 

$encrypted_password = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true).$salt);

this line covered salt in base64 but in node it does not, any idea @terry Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RutulPatel cool, let me just check the code and I'll update.

Comment: I've made an update to the code, you might give it a try, Thanks!

Comment: Great! It's a little more tricky than I thought,  but got there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

They both show different results because in your PHP code you have salt added while in NodeJs you some other salt. So that's why both have different hashes, but if you compare them using built in functions the result should return true.

```
npm install bcrypt
```

...

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("my password");

bcrypt.compareSync("my password", hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync("not my password", hash); // false
```